# jQuery mobile autocomplete doesn't show my websql data

Tags: jquery-mobile, autocomplete, web-sql

```
$("#username").autocomplete({

target: $('#usersss'),

source: function() {
            var db = decoara.webdb.db;

            db.transaction(function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql("SELECT codigo as value, fantasia as label, tabela FROM clientes WHERE fantasia LIKE '%"+$("#username").val()+"%' LIMIT 4",null, 

                    function (tx, results) {
                        jsonClientes = '[';
                        console.log('Rows:'+results.rows.length);

                        for (i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
                            row = results.rows.item(i);
                            jsonClientes += '{"value":'+row['value']+',"label":"'+row['label']+'"}';

                            if (i!=results.rows.length-1)
                                jsonClientes += ',';
                        }
                        jsonClientes += ']';
                        console.log(jsonClientes);
                        return $.parseJSON(jsonClientes);
                    },function (tx, e) {
                        console.log('error: ' + e.message);
                    }
                );  
            });
        },
        link: 'xxx.html?ops=',
        minLength: 1
    });
```

The source's function return this json code:

```
 [{"value":27,"label":"NARDIM"},{"value":38,"label":"MORO"},{"value":39,"label":"MH"},{"value":40,"label":"IRMAO SAPIENZA"}]
```

But the list-view just don't appear. When I change the source to a var using the same jSON data, it works fine:

```
var autocompleteData = $.parseJSON('[{"value":27,"label":"NARDIM"},{"value":38,"label":"MORO"},{"value":39,"label":"MH"},{"value":40,"label":"IRMAO SAPIENZA"}]');

source: autocompleteData,
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the jsonClientes as an array and then use .push to store values inside it.
i.e

```
var jsonClientes = [];
                        console.log('Rows:'+results.rows.length);

                        for (i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
                            row = results.rows.item(i);
                            jsonClientes.push ('{"value:"'+row.value+'",label:"'+row.label+'"},');
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The database stuff happens asyncronous. When the .autocomplete() gets called, the function on the "source" gets called and in there a database query is executed. But this database query tx.executeSql() will finish at any time in the future (async) and the "source" of the autocomplete will not have the result.

Unfortunately I have not found out how to solve this for those kind of jquery addons, so I went ahead to build an autocomplete around my specific database query. Basically, I start with the database query and provide a callback for the tx.executeSql() that will fill my autocomplete dropdown.